# Regex ignore case for match , but keep a specific case for results

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for an effective way to solve this problem

Let say we want to find a list of words in a string ignoring the case, but instead of storing the matched string we want a string with the same case as the original list.

For example :

```py
words_to_match = ['heLLo', 'jumP', 'TEST', 'RESEARCH stuff']
text = 'hello this is jUmp test jump and research stuff'
# Result should be {'TEST', 'heLLo', 'jumP', 'RESEARCH stuff'}
```

Here is my current approach:

```
words_to_match = ['heLLo', 'jumP', 'TEST', 'RESEARCH stuff']
```

I convert this to following regex :

```
regex = re.compile(r'\bheLLo\b|\bjumP\b|\bTEST\b|\bRESEARCH stuff\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Then

```py
word_founds = re.findall(regex,'hello this is jUmp test jump and research stuff')
normalization_dict = {w.lower():w for w in words_to_match}
# normalization dict : {'hello': 'heLLo', 'jump': 'jumP', 'test': 'TEST', 'research stuff': 'RESEARCH stuff'}
final_list = [normalization_dict[w.lower()] for w in word_founds]
# final_list : ['heLLo', 'jumP', 'TEST', 'jumP', 'RESEARCH stuff']
final_result = set(final_list)
# final_result : {'TEST', 'heLLo', 'jumP', 'RESEARCH stuff'}
```

This is my expected result, I just want to know if there is a faster/more elegant way to solve this problem.

Comment: How many words you got ?

Comment: To be clear I got the result that I wanted , I just want to know if there is something more elegant/faster.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single line, if you're still okay with using regex.

```py
results = set(word for word in re.findall(r"[\w']+", text) if word.lower() in [w.lower() for w in words_to_match])
```

All it's used for here is splitting the `text` variable based on word boundaries.

Edit:

You could also use:

```py
import string
results = set(word for word in "".join(c if c not in string.punctuation else " " for c in text).split() 
              if word.lower() in [w.lower() for w in words_to_match])
```

if you want to avoid importing `re`, but then you have to use `string`.

Edit 2: (after properly reading the question, hopefully)

```py
results = set(word for word in words_to_match if word.lower() in text.lower())
```

This works with multi-word searches as well.

Edit 3:

```py
results = set(word for word in words_to_match if re.search(r"\b" + word.lower() + r"\b", text.lower()))
```

Comment: Hi Collin, tank you for your solution, It helps me to figure out that I need to edit my question because basically inside the `words_to_match` I can have multi-words.

Comment: Even in the single word case your 1st solution get the case of the matched string and not the one of the orignal list.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread the question. That actually makes things a little easier; see my edit.

Comment: EDIT 2: Unfortunately it doesn't work (no word boundaries) see the comments on @Philosophist answer

Comment: Thanks it works :) ! However doing a search for each word is quiet slow compared to what I proposed, this is a toy example, but in reality the 'words_to_match' list is very long.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
words_to_match = ['heLLo', 'jumP', 'TEST'] 
text = 'hello this is jUmp test jump'
result = set()
for str in words_to_match:
    if str.lower() in text.lower():
        result.add(str)
```

Comment: @abcdaire Ah, doh'es me. Fixed.

Comment: With your solution there are no word boundaries, if you try with 'hellouu should not be captured' , it will capture 'hellouu' as heLLo

Comment: Ohh... hmm. Yeah, it doesn't get more elegant than using regex for that.

Comment: Yes I guess , I basically wanted to see if someone can come up with a solution that avoid the `normalization_dict`, thanks for your effort :)